# Too few invocations 0 when checking cardinality with Spock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, groovy, spock

I have a simpler controller method that does the following:

```
def updateName(){
    def idUser = params.id
    User changeUser = User.get(idUser)
    changeUser.name = "newname"
    changeUser.save(flush: true)
}
```

And the following Spock test:

```
def "updateName should edit user and save it"(){

given: "the id of the user"
    User currentUser = new User([name: "hector" , age: 12]).save(flush: true)
    params.id = User.last().id

when: "the updateName method is called"
    controller.updateName()

then: "name should have change it and save has to be called just one time"
    assert currentUser.name == "newname" // Success
    1 * _.save() // Too few invocations, 0.


}
```

I have seen all the related questions in SO about this topic, and people suggest using Mocks and Spy, but I don't really see why should I be using them and anyway I didn't get them to work for me, I tried to create a User mock and change my cardinality assert to:

```
1 * userMock.save()
```

But it didn't work for me... can I have some help with this?

Comment: Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then edit your question to become one. Incoherent code snippets without class names, imports, package names and lots of variables with undisclosed initialisation code are fine if you want to obfuscate your code, but not if you are looking for new insights from others what might be wrong with the code. For example: Where is `controller` initialised? What does the controller class look like (except for the one method you show)? Where is the `User` class?

Comment: 1) There is no need to initialize the "controller" in a groovy controller test spec 2) Why would u want to see the rest of my controller? MCVE asks for minimal information, not unnecessary one 3) if assert currentUser.name == "newname" is success, you don't need to know the rest of the information about my User class, just to know the save works for a string and a number. I don't find my snippets incoherent at all.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, I create a GroovyMock that allows me to access to static functions such as save.

```
def "updateName should edit user and save it"(){

given: "the id of the user"
    params.id = 1
    User mockUser = GroovyMock(User, global: true)

when: "the updateName method is called"
    controller.updateName()

then: "set Name and save has to be called just one time"
    1 * User.get(1) >> mockUser
    1 * mockUser.setName("newname")
    1 * mockUser.save()
} //All test passed!
```

Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it works for me! I'll leave the question in case someone offers a better solution, or throws some good information about this